# Hadoop output is weird

Tags: hadoop

I'm playing with Hadoop for the first time, and wrote a MapReducer to take a log file and chunk it down. However, the output is... weird.

It looks like this:

```
2f09 3133 3134 3838 0a2f 0009 3137 0a2f
0000 1908 efbf bd7b efbf bd44 11ef bfbd
efbf bd2a efbf bdef bfbd 301b 79ef bfbd
5bef bfbd d290 efbf bdef bfbd 5349 efbf
bd5c efbf bd24 32ef bfbd 7bef bfbd 58ef
bfbd efbf bd16 efbf bdef bfbd 20ef bfbd
52ef bfbd 1fd7 ac1b efbf bd21 672b df86
3603 031a 54ef bfbd efbf bd09 310a 2f00
002b efbf bd53 53ef bfbd 2bef bfbd efbf
bd63 6125 efbf bdef bfbd 3c17 024e 4eef
bfbd efbf bd1d 7e72 efbf bd18 efbf bd4b
2332 efbf bdef bfbd 04ef bfbd 1d19 efbf
bd67 5a33 3270 7bef bfbd 75ef bfbd 6def
bfbd 0931 0a2f 0000 46ef bfbd ddb5 efbf
bd4d 62ef bfbd 7751 2048 efbf bdef bfbd
14ef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 5463 efbf bdef
bfbd 5f12 efbf bdef bfbd 77ef bfbd 5fef
bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 32ef bfbd dd88 efbf
bdd8 b309 310a 2f00 0072 ccbd 0931 0a2f
0000 7457 efbf bdef bfbd 1632 efbf bdef
bfbd 21ef bfbd efbf bdef bfbd 563d 66ef
```

I did try it with a much smaller file originally, and it came up just fine in readable format. So I'm not entirely sure what the problem is... Has the encoding changed at some point in time while the file was being MapReduced?

I have absolutely no idea, so would appreciate some help to find out what's wrong, and what I can do to fix it, or to prevent it from happening again.

Thanks!

Edit: Added code

Thankfully, it's a nice short file since it's my first one ever... I've removed the imports and stuff to try to make it even shorter.

```
public class WCSLogParse {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

        private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(WCSLogParse.class);

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            line = splitToUrl(line);
            LOG.info("Line is "+line);
            if(line.contains(".")) {
                //do nothing
                LOG.info("Skipping line");
            }
            else {

                int lastSlash = line.lastIndexOf("/");
                line = line.substring(lastSlash);
                LOG.info("Command is "+line);

                context.write(new Text(line), one);

            }

        }

        private String splitToUrl(String line) {
            int subBegin = line.indexOf('/');
            int subEnd = line.indexOf(',',subBegin);
            if(subBegin == -1 || subEnd == -1) {
                return ".";
            }
            String url = line.substring(subBegin, subEnd);
            //handles if it is from a CSV field
            if(url.endsWith("\"")) {
                url = url.substring(0, (url.length()-1));
            }
            return url;
        }

        private String getUrl(String line) {

            String[] cols = line.split(",");

            return cols[7];

        }
    };

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

        System.out.println("the args are "+args.toString());

        Job job = new Job(conf, "WCSLogParse");
        job.setJarByClass(WCSLogParse.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

}
```

I'm kicking the job off in eclipse with the following arguments:

```
"/Volumes/Secondary Documents/logs/" "/Volumes/Secondary Documents/logs/output"
```

Comment: It looks like hexa no ? :D Please show us your code.

Comment: please show an input file too.

Comment: Converting that hex back into text makes no sense. So either this is a sequence file or compressed. None of both can be found in your code. Can you please share your core-site/mapred-site config of the cluster you are running? (Or the input is compressed)

Comment: Ugh. I'm so sorry. Thomas' comment made me look @ the input file again. I had both the compressed and the uncompressed logs in the same folder, so something must have made it start spitting out the output in a compressed format? Except, I don't understand why it would have looked in the compressed file format, and then mapped output from it? That said, I'm going to run it again - this time without the compressed logs in the same folder - and I'll post back.